# Python ctypes how to read array from a void pointer return

Tags: python, ctypes

So I am trying to read an unsigned short array which is returned by a void pointer in the c library I am using. The function definition in the header is like this:

```
void* Foo(int a, int b)
```

This function end up returning an a pointer to an array of type unsigned short.

In python I have been trying to return the array using ctypes without success. Here is what I have:

```
import ctypes
import numpy as np

libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("Library.dll")

Vec=np.zeros((1000,),dtype=np.uint16)

c_ushort_p = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ushort)
Vec_p=confVec.ctypes.data_as(c_ushort_p)

libc.Foo.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
Vec_p=libc.Foo(1,1)

print Vec_p
```

This returns "None".

If I try:

```
...
libc.Foo.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
Vec_p=libc.Foo(1,1)

print Vec_p[0]
```

I get TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'.

I also tried this:

```
...
libc.Foo.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
Vec_p=ctypes.cast(libc.Foo(1,1),c_ushort_p)

print Vec_p
```

Which returns , where print Vec_p[0] gives "ValueError: NULL pointer access"

Can anyone give me any assistance?

Comment: The 2nd attempt seems OK, but set `Foo.restype = c_ushort_p` instead of casting. Then, however you get the array `length`, you can use `np.ctypeslib.as_array(Foo(a, b), (length,))` to create a NumPy view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DLL is returning a null pointer. These are represented as None in ctypes.

I don't know why the function behaves that way but the output you see makes it quite clear that your function returns null.

Comment: Thank you. I assumed I was using ctypes wrong. As it turns out I have a simple error elsewhere in my program.